# Splitting subscription costs over fiscal year in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to create an Excel formula to split the costs of subscriptions across our fiscal year. For example, our fiscal year runs from July 1st - June 30th, but we have a subscription that runs from April 1st, 2018 to March 31st, 2019 costing $3,500. How can I create a formula for Excel to calculate how much of this subscription should be paid in FY18 (7-1-17 to 6-30-18) & how much should be paid in FY19 (7-1-18 TO 6-30-19)? Any help you can provide with this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your data up like so:

```
 |A              |B         |C         |D       |E    |F         |G         |H         |I
1|Item           |Start     |End       |Duration|Value|01/07/2017|01/07/2018|01/07/2019|01/07/2020
2|My Subscription|01/04/2018|31/03/2019|        |3500 |          |          |          |
```

With the following formulas:

```
D2  =YEAR(C2)-YEAR(B2)+(MONTH(C2)-MONTH(B2))/12+(DAY(C2)-DAY(B2))/365
F2  =$E2*IF(AND($B2 >= F$1,$B2 < G$1),IF(AND($C2 >= F$1,$C2 < G$1),1,(YEAR(G$1)-YEAR($B2)+(MONTH(G$1)-MONTH($B2))/12+(DAY(G$1)-DAY($B2))/365)/$D2),IF(AND($C2 >= F$1,$C2 < G$1),(YEAR($C2)-YEAR(F$1)+(MONTH($C2)-MONTH(F$1))/12+(DAY($C2)-DAY(F$1))/365)/$D2,IF(AND($B2 <= F$1,$C2 > F$1),1/$D2,0)))
^Copy this across to G2 and H2
```

This is pretty much taken from: https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/563602-split-value-across-fys-based-start-end-dates.html